# What does Alt Key refer to in Mac for codemirror commands?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, codemirror

In CodeMirror docs, https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#commands, there are some commands that use Alt key in Mac. But Mac does not have an Alt key.

For ex: Alt-B (Mac) is mapped to action goWordLeft.

1. Does codemirror docs refer to Mac's **Option** key in shortcuts that
   use **Alt** ?
2. If I want to add a key mapping for **Option-[** in Mac
   (and **Alt-[** in windows), how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Probably, if `option` and `alt` use the same keycode. I don't use mac so I cannot test it. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/) is a list of keycodes.
2. You can use keydown to detect which keys are down. Create an empty array where we will set our keys that are down. Once a key is down, add it to the keys array, if both keys you want are down, do something. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/esbm79gd/3/)

```
    var keys = {};
    $(document).on('keydown', '.CodeMirror', function(e) {
        var cm = $(this).closest('.codemirror_wrap'); // the editor's wrapper
        var editor = cm[0].editor;

        keys[e.which] = true; // set key[keycode pressed] to true 

        // detect if each key we want is down
        if (keys[18] && keys[219]) {
            // do something
        }
    });

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
    // remove this key from the keys array
        delete keys[e.which];
    });
```